# Bash “No such file or directory” but it exists

Tags: bash

I have this folder structure.

```
myFolder
 - script.sh
 - test.txt
```

In my script.sh, I wrote this code:

```
filepath = "test.txt"
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    this this this
done < filepath
```

I open terminal in `myFolder`, I type `bash script.sh` and I have this error:

```
No such file or directory
```

But `test.txt` contains 1 line.

Why do I have this error?

Comment: Do you have a command called `filepath`?  You've written `filepath = "test.txt"` but that runs the command `filepath` with two arguments: `=` and `test.txt` (since the shell removes the double quotes).  Also, your redirection looks for a file `filepath` (again); you probably intended to write `$filepath` which would look at the value in the variable — if the variable had been set. Run your code past [Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and see what it says.

Comment: And,  in general, it would be best to use double quotes around `"$filepath"` in the redirection, though with the fixed name shown, it isn't critical (there are no spaces to preserve, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Bash is actually quite sensitive about spaces. Also, you need to make sure you reference filepath as `$filepath`.

```
# no spaces around the equals sign
filepath="test.txt"
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    this this this
done < $filepath
# note the added $ above
```

Comment: See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -- questions that have been asked and answered many times before should be closed as duplicates so their answers can be centralized rather than spread out throughout the knowledgebase.

Comment: (Not my downvote, though -- while it's best not to add such answers, it's also not accepted practice to downvote them when accurate / otherwise acceptable. That said, it looks a little less like trying to game the system for rep if known-duplicate answers are added with the "community wiki" flag set).

Comment: Finding the right duplicate is a complete PITA.  I wonder if the [Upcoming Feature: New Question Close Experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394871/15168) is going to improve the tools for identifying duplicates?